# comma in javascript for loop conditional statement

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Time for some more education.

I've come across a javascript 'for loop' which loops through a nested object.  What does the ,10 portion, represent in the condition statement?

```
 for (var x = 0; x < parseInt(myObj[myCategory][MySubCategory]['amount'], 10); x++)
 {
// stuff happens
}
```

I am not finding any documentation that talks about this so I presume I'm just unclear on what I would even search on.  Thanks.

Comment: This would've been much cleaner (and possibly more efficient) if they had put `var length = parseInt(myObj[myCategory][MySubCategory]['amount'], 10);` in front of the loop, then have a `x < length` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, in your example, that `10` is the 2nd argument of the [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function.

The `,10` is for specifying a [base](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(mathematics)) of 10.

See [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters).

You'd think base 10 would be the default, but it isn't; you need to specify this each time you call the [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function.